# Get data from firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from firebase in sorted manner, I tried below method but its not working propely and collects all the data.

Here is the image for my firebase database :

[image: Database Image]

```
  DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        
String input = "G";
Date cd = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = df.format(cd);
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference data = databaseRef.child("Data").child(currentUser.getUid()).child(formattedDate.toString()).child(medname.toString());
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            data.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }
        Log.d("datafriebase",""+data);
    }
```

I want to get data in sorted manner, like value of 1, value of 2 but i am getting whole database

Comment: There isn't enough information to see what's wrong. What are the values of `currentUser.getUid()`, `formattedDate.toString()` and `medname.toString()` inside your reference? Besides that, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the whole database, because you're reading from `databaseRef`, which you initialized as:

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

To get only the nested data, read from `data`, which you set to reference that path:

```
DatabaseReference data = databaseRef.child("Data").child(currentUser.getUid()).child(formattedDate.toString()).child(medname.toString());
```

So:

```
data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```